# UI not update (have to click somewhere) & router not work in Angular2-Meteor

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

I cannot update the UI immediately after subscribing the data from database, I have to click somewhere

Also if I use the router to go to another page, it does not work

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-component',
  template: `
    {{foo}}
  `
})
export class FooComponent extends MeteorComponent {
  foo: string ;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.subscribe('messages', () => {
      // I cannot change foo value immediately, I have to click somewhere
      this.foo = 'foo';

      // Also if I use the router to go to another page, it does not work
      // this.router.navigate(['Home']);
    });
  }
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note the new angular2-meteor version  `autoBind` is set to true by default. So you probably won't meet this issue again.
>
> But you still need use NgZone in Accounts.changePassword or other similar Accounts.foo() functions.
>
> ---

This problem is because that part of code run out of Angular 2 zone, you need run it inside of zone to update UI immediately or use router to go to another page.

### Where do these problems usually happen?

Most time you don't do this. So when do you need this? Usually in callback of Meteor functions:

```
   this.autorun(() => {
     // here you need
   });

   this.subscribe('messages', () => {
     // here you need
   });

   this.call('newMessage', (error, result) => {
     // here you need
   });

   Accounts.changePassword(currentPassword, newPassword, error => {
     // here you need
   });
```

### How to solve?

Take

```
 this.call('newMessage', (error, result) => {
   this.router.navigate(['Home']);
 });
```

for example, you need change to:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

this.call('newMessage', (error, result) => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['Home']);
  });
});
```

### Is there a clean way?

Luckily, Angular2-Meteor helps you do this dirty work.

Check [Angular2-Meteor API document](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/angular2/0.4.2/meteorComponent), there is an `autoBind` parameter for `this.subscribe` and `this.autorun`.

So now you don't need use `this.zone.run`, instead you can just add a `true`:

```
   this.autorun(() => {
     // your code
   }, true);

   this.subscribe('messages', () => {
     // your code
   }, true);
```